# Is it possible to return a integer using Fn.conditionIf in CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk

Fn.conditionIf returns a ICfnConditionExpression which provides a way to get a String. Is there a way somehow using which I could get a Integer out of it?

Comment: Please add more information, this is unclear what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do the following

```js
new CfnCondition(this, 'Test', {
    expression: Fn.conditionEquals(parameter.valueAsString, 'test'),
});

const test = Fn.conditionIf('Test', 1, 2);

test.toString()

// Also has a resolve() method
```

Produces the following:

```
{
    "Fn::If": [
    "Test",
    1,
    2
    ]
}
```